# opencart to stop view index page until login

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

i am using opencart in one project,

every thing is working fine but i am unable to find an option to stop view of home page until LOGIN.

actually this is project requirement, no one can see home until LOGIN.

is there way to do this with OPEN CART ?

Thanks

Comment: Can they see any page or must they be forced to login from the start?  Do you want to use the basic login / register page or a special login page?  What version of opencart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is untested, but should point you in the right direction:

(OpenCart 1.4.9.x)

Save this to:
catalog/controller/common/check_login.php

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonCheckLogin extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
            // Require to be logged in
            $ignore = array(
                'account', 'payment'
            );

            $match = false;
            if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                foreach ($ignore as $i) {
                    if (strpos($this->request->get['route'], $i) !== false) {
                        $match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Show site if logged in as admin
            $this->load->library('user');
            $this->registry->set('user', new User($this->registry));

            if (!$this->user->isLogged() && !$match) {
                return $this->forward('account/login');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Edit /index.php

Find:

```
// Maintenance Mode
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance/check'));
```

Add After:

```
// Login Check
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/check_login'));
```

Essentially use the same logic as the maintenence check...  The big difference is it looks for the word 'account' in the string...  If it finds it it allows the page to be displayed, if not it redirects to the login page...

Use the word "account" instead of "login" in case they need to register...    All of the account pages already check for loggin so there is no worry there...

Again, untested so you may need to tweak one or two things - but it should/may work by dropping in the code

---

check_login.php for opencart 1.5.3

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonCheckLogin extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Require to be logged in
        if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {

            // Require to be logged in
            $ignore = array(
                'account','payment'
            );

            $match = false;
            if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
                foreach ($ignore as $i) {
                    if (strpos($this->request->get['route'], $i) !== false) {
                        $match = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Show site if logged in as admin
            $this->load->library('user');

            $this->user = new User($this->registry);

            if (!$this->user->isLogged() && !$match) {
                $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login'));
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i have opencart_v1.5.1.3.1 and can't find $controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance/check'));

Comment: For opencart 1.5.1.3.x it is line 221 in the raw/unedited version of /index.php

Comment: Just edited my answer: It will also need payment in the ignore array - otherwise it will reject payment callbacks

Comment: yes i add the $controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/check_login')); after line 221 in index.php but still not working

Comment: did you add check_login.php file to /catalog/common/check_login.php    Are you logged in as an admin ?  (It checks for user login and then admin login...)

Comment: sir my check_login.php file is in catalog\controller\common and i am also not login as admin

Comment: and i have this code in index.php file  
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));


$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/check_login'));

Comment: Can you post your index and check_login files to pastebin

Comment: sure sie for index.php file "http://pastebin.com/u1MvkcUn" and for check_login.php "http://pastebin.com/wxJf5jSt"

Comment: I did a new pastebin for an alternate version (structured like 1.5.x)   http://pastebin.com/MuHNQJzg    give it a try..  The first should be working though...

Comment: i dont know what's problem, as i am new to opencart but still this new class is not working. i am so sorry for that

Comment: No worries.. Give me a minute, I am installing a fresh version of OC 1.5.3 to test

Comment: dear Sir, please look at attached image... as now i just change the theme to default to got login page, but still showing the banner and other stuff   http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/840/unledmyn.png/

Comment: this is just adding login page in the HOME page just under the featured product and above the company logos.

Comment: Added a 1.5.3 updated version to the bottom of my answer...   I was origionally testing with a modified version of OC...  This one works with a clean install..

Comment: yes it worked....... Thanks vary much so much appreciated. its really good code for any one who is searching for same, once again so nice of you :)

Comment: Anytime..  Just remember to select it as the answer on StackOverflow :)      If you ever need any detailed advice beyond the scope of a S.O. question, feel free to email me at the addy in my profile...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in that I know of, but you can do it yourself. Based on your answers to @CarpeNoctumDC's questions you may have to do some digging, but this should get you started:

**system/library/customer.php**

```
public function isLogged() { ... }
```

**catalog/controller/common/home.php**

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
    // login page
    exit;
}
```

Comment: why are you modifying the isLogged function? It is fine...   Also, the problem with that solution is if they use an SEO url they can still view any other than the home page...

Comment: I wasn't suggesting modifying the isLogged() function, I was simply pointing out where the isLogged() function lived in case he wanted to go looking. And yes I know it isn't a complete solution, because the question was incomplete and there was no response to your comment, I was just giving some idea of how to "get started".

Answer (score 0):

The right way to go about this is to open

> /catalog/controller/common/home.php

find `public function index() {` at the top of the code, and after it put

```
if(!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
    $this->url->redirect('account/login', '', 'SSL');
}
```

In case you're unsure how to do this properly, just take a look at the first few lines after `public function index() {` in

> /catalog/controller/account/account.php

setting your code in the home controller to `common/home` in place of `account/account`